# getting exception at expect interact command

Tags: linux, bash, shell, expect

```
[Linux Dev:as ~]$ cat expectsh1.sh
echo "hi"
echo "world"
echo "hello"


[Linux Dev:as ~]$ cat expectshmain.sh
#!/usr/bin/expect

spawn "./expectsh1.sh"

expect "hello" { send "12\r" }
expect "hi" { send "23\r" }

interact
```

Getting Exception as below for interact statement :

```
[Linux Dev:as ~]$ ./expectshmain.sh
spawn ./expectsh1.sh
hi
world
hello
12
spawn_id: spawn id exp6 not open
while executing
"interact"
    (file "./expectshmain.sh" line 8)
```

Could any one please let me know whats the issue caused and solution for problem. What is the purpose of using interact command in shell..?

Comment: `interact` *is not* a shell command; it's an expect command, and expect is not a shell language (it's TCL). `expect` should only be used when you have a command which is otherwise impossible to control without human interaction, and you do not have one of those use cases.

Comment: Also, as they are not shell scripts, expect scripts should not be given names ending in `.sh`. (Neither should shell scripts -- see https://www.talisman.org/~erlkonig/documents/commandname-extensions-considered-harmful -- but that's a longer discussion).

Answer (score 0):

The purpose is to give control of the spawned program to the human at the keyboard. In this case, after you expect "hello", the spawned program is finished running.

If you don't actually want to interact with the spawned program, if you just want the expect script to exit cleanly, use `expect eof`

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to demonstrate use of expect, consider rewriting your scripts as such:

```
cat >expectsh1 <<'EOF'
#!/bin/sh
echo "hi"
read -r first_num
echo "world"
read -r second_num
echo "You entered $first_num and then $second_num"

# ...and do something with further human interaction
while read -r; do
  echo "You entered: $REPLY"
done
EOF

cat >expect-test <<'EOF'
#!/usr/bin/expect

spawn "./expectsh1"

expect "hello" { send "12\r" }
expect "hi" { send "23\r" }

interact
EOF
```